# onItemClickListener not working for List items (using Fragments)

Tags: android, listview

I am slightly confused as how to make my list items clickable and would appreciate any help on this one.

My hierarchy:

1 - Activity that has PagerSlidingTabStrip and ViewPager (to show tabs and swipe between Fragments)

```
<RelativeLayout>
    ... some other stuff ...
    <LinearLayout>
        <com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip />
        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Depending on which tab is clicked it shows one of the 2 fragments.

2- The fragment that I need to use here has:

```
<FrameLayout>
    <ListView />
</FrameLayout>
```

3 - This is what goes inside the ListView:

```
<LinearLayout>
    <RelativeLayout>
        <TextView />
        <TextView />
        <TextView />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The RelativeLayout is what needs to be clicked (it's a rectangle that shows the item details).
I've attached an onItemClickListener to the ListView and when I click on the items they sometime do click but like every 10th time but not every time, I suspect that it doesn't recognise the click for the big rectangle and instead reads the click for either one of those TextViews or maybe something else?

I've tried some voodoo magic with focusable, clickable, textIsSelectable but got completely confused as what needs to go where. I don't completely get what gets priority here.

In any case thanks!

Comment: You have shared everything else and not the code which is not working

Comment: Because there isn't any code. I've tried several onItemClickListener's that did the same, they both worked and were producing stuff when the click was registered. The problem is that the click doesn't register every time I tap on the item.

Answer (score 0):

You have **3 TextView** elements, for your ListView. Set the `setOnClickListener` on any of the **TextView**. The issue is that Listview overlaps all the 3 TextView, and the framework will only trigger onto one GUI object.
Try it out and let us know.

Comment: I've set a setOnClickListener  to one of the TextView's and it clicks when I tap exactly on that TextView. But I need it to work on the whole Layout. :)

Comment: user45173, Are you saying that you still have a problem?  If so, you can use the attr layout_alignParentLeft , right, or middle in the TextViews. If so, I'll update my answer. If you think my answer if helpful, please do so.

Comment: The Original Android, is there any way to avoid making the TextViews clickable and instead the Layout in which they are? Or somehow to make the onItemClickListener for the ListView to work properly. :/

Comment: user45173, My experience says no, you could not make the listener work for ListView due to conflicts on the overlapping layout. Look at it this way, when an item row is clicked, you still have to know which row position is clicked upon. It will be harder for the ListView object to find which row is clicked upon. Whereas, the getView method of the Adapter gives you the row item. Does that make sense?